# is this loop invariant and post condition correct?

Tags: algorithm, invariants, hoare-logic

I was trying to write a loop invariant and post condition for this code:

```
sum = 0;
for (i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
  ++sum;
```

`sum = 10` is the obvious post condition here. But a friend told me that `i = sum` is also a loop invariant and `sum = 12` is also a post condition. I checked the following:

- loop invariant is initially true: that's true for `i = sum` since both are 0 initially
- loop invariant is preserved: assume `i < 10` and `i = sum` then after one iteration it's still true that `++i = ++sum`
- loop invariant implies post condition: assume `i >= 10` and `i = sum` then `sum = 12` is also true

But obviously sum doesn't equal to 12 here. So what's wrong with my reasoning here?

Comment: The way the for loop works makes sure that `i = 10` not only `i >= 10` after the loop.

Comment: @henry I thought Hoare logic states that "assume the loop condition is no longer true and loop invariant is true then the post condition is true." In this case "loop condition is no longer true" means !(i < 10) hence i >= 10?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a slightly different invariant `i == sum && i <= 10`. Together with `i >= 10` you get then `i = sum = 10`.

Btw. in your original reasoning you cannot conclude that `sum = 12` is true but only that `sum >= 10`. The latter is correct, just not strong enough to prove the desired result.

Answer (score 1):

```
// Loop invariant SUM_IS_INDEX: sum == i
// Loop variant: i is increased in every step, and initial value 0 before 10.

sum = 0;
for (i = 0;
        // SUM_IS_INDEX      before the actual loop
        i < 10;
        // next loop step, after first step:
        // sum == index + 1
        ++i
        // next index = index + 1
        // sum == index
        // SUM_IS_INDEX      after a loop step, continuing
        ) {
    // SUM_IS_INDEX
    ++sum;
    // sum == index + 1
}
// Post: i >= 10 (negation of the for condition), SUM_IS_INDEX
```

The comment about 12 relates more to `i`. To have `i == 10` one would need to add a predicate on increments of just 1.

**Best practise is to rewrite the for in control flow order:**

```
sum = 0;
i = 0;
while (i < 10)
    ++sum;
    ++i:
}
```

This prevents silly mistakes.